# Struggling with ajax PUT request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

EDIT: No longer getting an undefined URI once I passed $(this).attr('red') to a variable. Still getting the 500 Server error though.

EDIT: [Here is all the code on github](https://github.com/WayneHaworth/nodetest2.git) (just in case I have missed something!)

EDIT: Here is the how the function is called in global.js

```
$('#userList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkedituser', editUser);
```

And here is the html.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="userInfo">
      <h2>User Info</h2>

      <p><strong>Name:</strong> <span id='userInfoName'></span><br />
      <strong>Age:</strong> <span id='userInfoAge'></span><br />
      <strong>Gender:</strong> <span id='userInfoGender'></span><br />
      <strong>Location:</strong> <span id='userInfoLocation'></span></p>
    </div>

    <h2>User List</h2>

    <div id="userList">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>

            <th>Email</th>

            <th>Delete</th>

            <th>Edit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>

    <h2>Edit User</h2>

    <div id="editUser">
      <fieldset>
        <input id="editUserName" type="text" placeholder="Username" /><input id=
        "editUserEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email" /><br />
        <input id="editUserFullname" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" /><input id=
        "editUserAge" type="text" placeholder="Age" /><br />
        <input id="editUserLocation" type="text" placeholder="Location" /><input id=
        "editUserGender" type="text" placeholder="Gender" /><br />
        <button id="btnEditUser">Edit User</button>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to submit a form as a PUT request to edit a user's information.

I receive the following error in my Chrome console when I submit the form.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (undefined, line 0)
```

The right of the error shows the ID just fine so I imagine this is something to do with the router end?

```
http://localhost:3000/users/edituser/53fa0acbc069f52257312d2c
```

Here is my client side function.

```
function editUser(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var thisUserID = $(this).attr('rel');
var arrayPosition = userListData.map(function(arrayItem) { return arrayItem._id;    }).indexOf(thisUserID);

var thisUserObject = userListData[arrayPosition];

$('#editUserName').val(thisUserObject.email);
$('#editUserEmail').val(thisUserObject.email);
$('#editUserFullname').val(thisUserObject.fullname);
$('#editUserAge').val(thisUserObject.age);
$('#editUserLocation').val(thisUserObject.location);
$('#editUserGender').val(thisUserObject.gender);

var editUser = {
  'username' : $('#editUserName').val(),
  'email' : $('#editUserEmail').val(),
  'fullname' : $('#editUserFullname').val(),
  'age' : $('#editUserAge').val(),
  'location' : $('#editUserLocation').val(),
  'gender' : $('#editUserGender').val(),
}

//just a test to prove that I can read the id from the db
$('body > h1').text($(this).attr('rel'));

$('#btnEditUser').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/users/edituser/' + thisUserID,
    data: JSON.stringify(editUser),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) { alert('Success'); },
    error: function(err) {alert('Error'); }
  }).done(function(response) {
    if (response.msg === '') {
    }
    else {
      alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
    } 
    populateTable();
  });
});
};
```

Here is my router on the server side inside /routes/users.js.

```
router.put('/edituser/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var userToEdit = req.params('id');

    db.collection('userlist').findById(userToEdit, function(err, result) {
        res.send((result === 1) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: 'error: ' + err });
    });
});
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: well if it is undefined than `$(this).attr('rel')` is not returning anything...

Comment: Let's see the HTML too.

Comment: @apsillers I can get the rel value (the object ID) to alert just fine if I use your anon function above. For ref it shows the value '53fa0acbc069f52257312d2c'.

Comment: @Kenny I have included the HTML as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You are pulling the `id` from the body, when it's in the url.

So replace `var userToEdit = req.body.id;` with:

```
var userToEdit = req.params.id;
```

Or you can use `req.param('id')` which goes through [all the methods](http://expressjs.com/api#req.param) to find the value.

Also do `res.json(..)` instead of `res.send(..)`.

Comment: This one gets me all the time, I usually forget to use params and use body or query by accident ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, I am still having the problem but I would have run into the this issue soon enough! :) I will edit my question to include your change.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue regarding the "undefined" URI by sending $(this).attr('rel') into a variable so it could be retrieved from within the submit click event.

I am still having issues but will open a new question as much has changed.